# Enable automatic tooltips in Altair 3.0

Tags: python, altair

I noticed the [Vega-Lite 3.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/releases/tag/v3.0.0) mentioned "Tooltips are included by default," and this is true for boxplots in Altair 3.0, but not for other plots like histograms.

When I open my Altair plots in the Vega Editor, I see `"mark": {"tooltip": null}}` in the `config` section at the top of the chart definition. If I remove `"mark": {"tooltip": null}`, tooltips work automatically.

So, instead of [this](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDGD2B2AzAlgc0gLjMSA3ZApgO6baRHIAmALgBakAsADEwDRS0Fq3WkDMLAL7tIAWwCGAJwDWpHNViwANtWQAHUvACuSpYOHgolcdXFzDESFslLSkHtTUBnDAHpXuAqnEA6VMjotACMfZFgPL3EAWmNTJwJqJ1dY8Vd4k2olAijqAlFnH2gnXEhDA0sJGTsgqUhWQ0gCeDhKZHh0LFAISwAPOUhqAE81AjsARy1xeFVTVU86qCC20mpJLQIRFAIlSjtc-Mhy7shB-qGR8cnpgJNkeZFxVFRJSNy7OC1pw7L6ywASJzQTgSOwOZxuCLePwBWjBULhQHA1KebxRJQBAgePg+ABMPgAjD4AFZOBClQRAA):

```
{
  "config": {"view": {"width": 400, "height": 300}, "mark": {"tooltip": null}},
  "data": {
    "url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/seattle-temps.csv"
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "bin": true, "field": "temp"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "count"}
  },
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.2.1.json"
}
```

I would like the Altair output to be like [this](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDGD2B2AzAlgc0gLjMSA3ZApgO6baRHIAmALgBakAsADEwDRS0Fq3WkDMLAL6DW4KJQCG1CaVAQIkAK4AnADalIPagAcAzhgD0B3AVQSAdKmR1FAI3PJYx0xIC0k6boLVdBjxIMvKWpVAldqAgBbPXNoXVxIMRExSEiJZQBrDVt0yFEFAng4SmR4dCw5eUgAD1lIagBPbQINAEdFCXhqaylkEzyoW1LSamVFAnZIFAJVSg0I6Mhk+SgGusbmto6unu7+yYlUVGUXCI04RS6lpPyoABJdaE40jS09Q2czS2taOwcnR7PAImMyuVTWAjGPjmABM5gAjOYAFa6BCJQRAA):

```
{
  "config": {"view": {"width": 400, "height": 300}},
  "data": {
    "url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/seattle-temps.csv"
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "bin": true, "field": "temp"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "count"}
  },
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.2.1.json"
}
```

Is there a way to prevent Altair from disabling tooltips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We made the choice to disable automatic tooltips because Vega-Lite will disable them in the near future. If you would like to enable default tooltips in a particular chart, you can use, e.g.

```py
alt.Chart(data).mark_point(tooltip=alt.TooltipContent('encoding'))
```

or

```py
chart.configure_mark(tooltip=alt.TooltipContent('encoding'))
```

If you want every chart in your session to include that setting, you can create an [altair theme](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/configuration.html#altair-themes) that enables this by default. For example:

```py
def tooltips():
  return {'config': {'mark': {'tooltip': {'content': 'encoding'}}}}

alt.themes.register('tooltips', tooltips)
alt.themes.enable('tooltips')
```